# TinyMCE 4 with elFinder

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, elfinder

Is somebody already tried to integrate elFinder into new (4b1) version of TinyMCE?
It looks like [previous](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/how-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser) [implementation](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-TinyMCE-3.x) isn't working.
Please post some snippets, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution:

1. Create folder in plugins named elfinder.
2. Download latest [elFinder](http://elfinder.org/) and put into this folder plugins/elfinder.
3. Add plugin 'elfinder' to the list of plugins (tinymce.init).
4. Rename js/elfinder.min.js to js/plugin.min.js
5. Create file plugin.min.js in root folder of plugin (elfinder/plugin.min.js)
6. Insert next text inside and save:

> tinymce.PluginManager.add("elfinder", function (editor, url) {
>
> editor.settings.file_browser_callback = function (id, value, type,
>   win)    {
>
> ```
>   $('<div />').dialogelfinder({
>      url: url + '/php/connector.php',
>      commandsOptions: {
>         getfile: {
>            oncomplete: 'destroy'
>         }
>      },
>      getFileCallback: function (url)
>      {
>         var fieldElm = win.document.getElementById(id);
>         fieldElm.value = editor.convertURL(url, null, true);
>         if ("fireEvent"in fieldElm) {
>            fieldElm.fireEvent("onchange")
>         } else {
>            var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
>            evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
>            fieldElm.dispatchEvent(evt)
>         }
>      }
>   });
> ```
>
> }; 
>   }, ["elfinder/js"]);

Comment: You did everything like I said?

Comment: @dikirill can this be used on rails 2? I'm getting an error `Cannot call method 'dialogelfinder' of null` browser console

Answer (score 6):

I updated the Wiki, should work now when following the steps: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-TinyMCE-4.x

Primary changes are that TinyMCE doesn't use the InlinePopup plugin any more, the callback is changed and instead of `file_browser_callback : 'elFinderBrowser'` you have to remove the quotes:

In the TinyMCE init:
`file_browser_callback : elFinderBrowser`

Add the elFinderBrowser callback to your javascript:

```
function elFinderBrowser (field_name, url, type, win) {
  tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    file: '/elfinder/elfinder.html',// use an absolute path!
    title: 'elFinder 2.0',
    width: 900,  
    height: 450,
    resizable: 'yes'
  }, {
    setUrl: function (url) {
      win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

And finally modify/copy elfinder.html file to use the callback:

```
<!-- Include jQuery, jQuery UI, elFinder (REQUIRED) -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  var FileBrowserDialogue = {
    init: function() {
      // Here goes your code for setting your custom things onLoad.
    },
    mySubmit: function (URL) {
      // pass selected file path to TinyMCE
      top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.getParams().setUrl(URL);

      // close popup window
      top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
    }
  }

  $().ready(function() {
    var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
      // set your elFinder options here
      url: 'php/connector.php',  // connector URL
      getFileCallback: function(file) { // editor callback
        FileBrowserDialogue.mySubmit(file.url); // pass selected file path to TinyMCE 
      }
    }).elfinder('instance');      
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The link to documentation at the beginning of the post has the correct code. At least the code from there worked for me!

Comment: does anyone have an idea what the init function is for?