# TinyMCE 4 with elFinder integration

Tags: elfinder, tinymce-4

I tried to integrate elFinder in TinyMCE 4 and followed the following thread:

[TinyMCE 4 with elFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016870/tinymce-4-with-elfinder)

I followed all the steps exactly but I get the following error in the js console when I click the button to open the image browsing window:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'dialogelfinder' of null

This refers to the line

```
$('<div />').dialogelfinder({
```

What can I be doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow original way of integration from their wiki:
https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-TinyMCE-4.x