# Tinymce image upload not working in cakephp 3.( by JustBoil plugin)

Tags: cakephp, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to add image upload option in tinymce editor using [this](http://justboil.me/) plugin.

I have downloaded tinymce and keep it in `webroot/js/tinymce` folder. Then I downloaded justboil plugin, and keep it in `tinymce/plugin` folder. Then I have tried this code in my add.ctp file

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('details',['class'=>'tinymce']);  ?>
```

I have used this js code below

```
    <script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'.tinymce',
           plugins: "jbimages,code"
        });
   </script>
```

Not it's looking like below image and working fine and also saving code data in database table.
  [image]

After trying a image upload it's giving a code like

[image]

In `tinymce\plugins\jbimages\config.php` file , I have given bellow setting

```
$config['img_path'] = '/tinymce/images';
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path'];
```

// same code working fine in php, but not in cakephp. May anyone help me please ?

I have been solve this problem, but still not 100 % accuracy. I am shearing my ans and also need a help to define path.

After add `relative_urls: false` in tinymce.init

```
tinymce.init({selector:'.tinymce',
           plugins: "jbimages,code",
           relative_urls: false
});
```

and I have also changed upload directory in config.php

```
$config['img_path'] = '/photobag.in/photobag/img';
```

All is working fine. Here in config.php file  how can I dynamically define base_url? For example here photobag.in is my project folder.It may I will change it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TinyMCE 4 with elFinder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016870/tinymce-4-with-elfinder)

Comment: follow this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016870/tinymce-4-with-elfinder